# serialize Javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, serialization

I want to be able to store objects as code in mongo DB.
the main problem is when trying to store an `array` that contain types..
Example: [`String`, `Array`, `'some'`, `'hello world'`].
When saving and getting the document I would get

```
Doc.array = [undefined, undefined, 'some', 'hello world']
```

Is there a way to serialize the array it self and save it in mongo ?
Something like:

```
var S = require('serializer');
var obj = {
    cons: [[String, 'some', 'somemore']],
    func: function(param, param2){
        param2.some = 'bla';
    }
};

var objs = S.serializer(obj);

//Store that serialized obj as a value for binary key or buffer key in mongo..
// then when getting the document...

var obj = S.deserialize(objs);
// being obj the exactly same object with the array and the function.
```

Is there a way to do this, or is there a different/better approach ?

**Edit**

I just need a way to store a [nools](https://github.com/C2FO/nools#defining-rule) rule, so the problem is that the rule constraints structure is the following:

```
[FactType, 'alias', 'conditions']
```

Where FactType could be String, Object, Custom.

Comment: `String` is (or rather, refers to) a function. What exactly do you want stored in Mongo for it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder take a look to my edit. Would be great if there is a way to serialize that but keep String just for a reference.. not the string function it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If It's Just A JSON You Can stringify A Json :

```
var text=JSON.stringify(obj);
```

And Parse To Jason Again By parse :

`var myVar=JSON.parse(text`);

If You Have Functions In The Object Use This To Serialize:

```
function objToString(obj, ndeep) {
  switch(typeof obj){
    case "string": return '"'+obj+'"';
    case "function": return obj.name || obj.toString();
    case "object":
      var indent = Array(ndeep||1).join('\t'), isArray = Array.isArray(obj);
      return ('{['[+isArray] + Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
           return '\n\t' + indent +(isArray?'': key + ': ' )+ objToString(obj[key], (ndeep||1)+1);
         }).join(',') + '\n' + indent + '}]'[+isArray]).replace(/[\s\t\n]+(?=(?:[^\'"]*[\'"][^\'"]*[\'"])*[^\'"]*$)/g,'');
    default: return obj.toString();
  }
}
```

Example

Serialize:

```
var text=objToString(obj); //To Serialize Object
```

Result:

```
"{cons:[[String,"some","somemore"]],func:function(param,param2){param2.some='bla';}}"
```

Unserialize:

```
Var myObj=eval('('+text+')');//To UnSerialize
```

Result:

```
Object {cons: Array[1], func: function, spoof: function}
```